# getting a conditional sum with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

my query returns data that looks like this:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+------+------+------+------+-----+
| Jan  | Feb  | Mar  | Apr  | May  | Jun  | Jul  |  Aug  | Sep  | Oct  | Nov  | Dec  | bla |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+------+------+------+------+-----+
|    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |     0 |    0 |    0 |    2 |    0 |  13 |
|    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |     0 |    0 |    2 |    0 |    0 |  14 |
|    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    9 |    0 |     0 |    0 |    0 |    8 |   37 |  29 |
|    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |     0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |  374 |  30 |
|    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |   78 |    2 |    4 |     8 |   57 |  169 |  116 |  602 |  31 |
|  156 |  255 |   79 |   75 |  684 |  325 |  289 |   194 |  407 |  171 |  584 |  443 |  32 |
| 1561 | 2852 | 2056 |  796 | 2004 | 1755 |  879 |  1052 | 1490 | 1683 | 2532 | 2381 |  33 |
| 4167 | 3841 | 4798 | 3399 | 4132 | 5849 | 3157 |  4381 | 4424 | 4487 | 4178 | 5343 |  34 |
| 5472 | 5939 | 5768 | 4150 | 7483 | 6836 | 6346 |  6288 | 6850 | 7155 | 5706 | 5231 |  35 |
| 5749 | 4741 | 5264 | 4045 | 6544 | 7405 | 7524 |  6625 | 6344 | 5508 | 6513 | 3854 |  36 |
| 5464 | 6323 | 7074 | 4861 | 7244 | 6768 | 6632 |  7389 | 8077 | 8745 | 6738 | 5039 |  37 |
| 5731 | 7205 | 7476 | 5734 | 9103 | 9244 | 7339 |  8970 | 9726 | 9089 | 6328 | 5512 |  38 |
| 7262 | 6149 | 8231 | 6654 | 9886 | 9834 | 9306 | 10065 | 9983 | 9984 | 6738 | 5806 |  39 |
| 5886 | 6934 | 7137 | 6978 | 9034 | 9155 | 7389 |  9437 | 9711 | 8665 | 6593 | 5337 |  40 |
| 5680 | 5167 | 5385 | 5434 | 5548 | 6587 | 8688 |  8246 | 9372 | 7723 | 5805 | 7123 |  41 |
| 3752 | 3550 | 5425 | 4902 | 3153 | 4499 | 4420 |  4575 | 5892 | 6553 | 4927 | 6245 |  42 |
| 2829 | 5561 | 4881 | 4919 | 3779 | 2781 | 3503 |  3898 | 4090 | 4268 | 3946 | 5864 |  43 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+------+------+------+------+-----+
```

when BLA (the last field) is greater than 40, i want it to just sum all the values and print `41` as the last line:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
|  Jan  |  Feb  |  Mar  |  Apr  |  May  |  Jun  |  Jul  |  Aug  |  Sep  |  Oct  |  Nov  |  Dec  | bla |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
|     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     2 |     0 |  13 |
|     1 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     2 |     0 |     0 |  14 |
|     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     9 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     8 |    37 |  29 |
|     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     1 |     0 |   374 |  30 |
|     0 |     0 |     1 |     0 |    78 |     2 |     4 |     8 |    57 |   169 |   116 |   602 |  31 |
|   156 |   255 |    79 |    75 |   684 |   325 |   289 |   194 |   407 |   171 |   584 |   443 |  32 |
|  1561 |  2852 |  2056 |   796 |  2004 |  1755 |   879 |  1052 |  1490 |  1683 |  2532 |  2381 |  33 |
|  4167 |  3841 |  4798 |  3399 |  4132 |  5849 |  3157 |  4381 |  4424 |  4487 |  4178 |  5343 |  34 |
|  5472 |  5939 |  5768 |  4150 |  7483 |  6836 |  6346 |  6288 |  6850 |  7155 |  5706 |  5231 |  35 |
|  5749 |  4741 |  5264 |  4045 |  6544 |  7405 |  7524 |  6625 |  6344 |  5508 |  6513 |  3854 |  36 |
|  5464 |  6323 |  7074 |  4861 |  7244 |  6768 |  6632 |  7389 |  8077 |  8745 |  6738 |  5039 |  37 |
|  5731 |  7205 |  7476 |  5734 |  9103 |  9244 |  7339 |  8970 |  9726 |  9089 |  6328 |  5512 |  38 |
|  7262 |  6149 |  8231 |  6654 |  9886 |  9834 |  9306 | 10065 |  9983 |  9984 |  6738 |  5806 |  39 |
|  5886 |  6934 |  7137 |  6978 |  9034 |  9155 |  7389 |  9437 |  9711 |  8665 |  6593 |  5337 |  40 |
| 12261 | 14278 | 15691 | 15255 | 12480 | 13867 | 16611 | 16719 | 19354 | 18544 | 14678 | 19232 |  41 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
```

as you can see that last line is a sum of everything `41` and greater.

here's my query:

```
select 
sum(case when datepart(month,[datetime entered]) = 1 then 1 end) as Jan,
sum(case when datepart(month,[datetime entered]) = 2 then 1 end) as Feb,
sum(case when datepart(month,[datetime entered]) = 3 then 1 end) as Mar,
sum(case when datepart(month,[datetime entered]) = 4 then 1 end) as Apr,
sum(case when datepart(month,[datetime entered]) = 5 then 1 end) as May,
sum(case when datepart(month,[datetime entered]) = 6 then 1 end) as Jun,
sum(case when datepart(month,[datetime entered]) = 7 then 1 end) as Jul,
sum(case when datepart(month,[datetime entered]) = 8 then 1 end) as Aug,
sum(case when datepart(month,[datetime entered]) = 9 then 1 end) as Sep,
sum(case when datepart(month,[datetime entered]) = 10 then 1 end) as Oct,
sum(case when datepart(month,[datetime entered]) = 11 then 1 end) as Nov,
sum(case when datepart(month,[datetime entered]) = 12 then 1 end) as Dec,
DATEPART(yyyy,[datetime entered]) as [Year],
 bla= CASE WHEN datediff(d, CAST([datetime entered] as DATE), CAST([datetime completed] as DATE))*24 + 
 CONVERT(CHAR(2),[datetime completed],108)
 >41 THEN 41 ELSE datediff(d, CAST([datetime entered] as DATE), CAST([datetime completed] as DATE))*24 + 
 CONVERT(CHAR(2),[datetime completed],108)  END


from [TurnAround]

where DATEPART(yyyy,[datetime entered])=2011

group by 

datediff(d, CAST([datetime entered] as DATE), CAST([datetime completed] as DATE))*24 + 
 CONVERT(CHAR(2),[datetime completed],108),

 DATEPART(yyyy,[datetime entered])

 order by bla
```

**how do i get the results as shown in the second example where everything past `41` is summed?**

thanks so much for your guidance and help!!

Comment: Please would you provide more clarity on what bla is. From what I can see, it's the number of hours from `[date entered]` to `[date completed]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that you calculate `BLA` taking that condition in consideration. But, another way is just using your current query as a derived table and use a `CASE`:

```
SELECT  SUM(Jan) Jan,
        SUM(Feb) Feb,
        SUM(Mar) Mar,
        SUM(Apr) Apr,
        SUM(May) May,
        SUM(Jun) Jun,
        SUM(Jul) Jul,
        SUM(Aug) Aug,
        SUM(Sep) Sep,
        SUM(Oct) Oct,
        SUM(Nov) Nov,
        SUM(Dec) Dec,
        CASE WHEN Bla >= 41 THEN 41 ELSE Bla END Bla
FROM (Your current query here) DT
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Bla >= 41 THEN 41 ELSE Bla END;
```

Or a CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    Your current query here
)
SELECT  SUM(Jan) Jan,
        SUM(Feb) Feb,
        SUM(Mar) Mar,
        SUM(Apr) Apr,
        SUM(May) May,
        SUM(Jun) Jun,
        SUM(Jul) Jul,
        SUM(Aug) Aug,
        SUM(Sep) Sep,
        SUM(Oct) Oct,
        SUM(Nov) Nov,
        SUM(Dec) Dec,
        CASE WHEN Bla >= 41 THEN 41 ELSE Bla END Bla
FROM CTE
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Bla >= 41 THEN 41 ELSE Bla END;
```

Comment: +1 : By the time I worked out what this question was asking you had already posted the answer I would have used.  Nice job :)

Comment: @Dems - Thanks. I did had to look closely at the expected data, otherwise I wouldn't have understood what was asked.

Comment: Oh. Snap! Much the same thing, so I wouldn't have bothered if I'd seen that you'd already come up with it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a common table expression, as follows, although I'm not entirely sure what bla represents; I'm assuming its the number of hours from entry to completion:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT 
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, [datetime entered]) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Jan,
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, [datetime entered]) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Feb,
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, [datetime entered]) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Mar,
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, [datetime entered]) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Apr,
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, [datetime entered]) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS May,
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, [datetime entered]) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Jun,
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, [datetime entered]) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Jul,
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, [datetime entered]) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Aug,
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, [datetime entered]) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Sep,
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, [datetime entered]) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Oct,
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, [datetime entered]) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Nov,
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, [datetime entered]) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Dec,
    DATEPART(yyyy, [datetime entered]) AS [Year],
    FLOOR(CAST([datetime completed] AS FLOAT) - CAST([datetime entered] AS FLOAT) * 24) AS bla
)
SELECT SUM(Jan) AS Jan, SUM(Feb) AS Feb, SUM(Mar) AS Mar, SUM(Apr) AS Apr, SUM(May) AS May, SUM(Jun) AS Jun, 
    SUM(Jul) AS Jul, SUM(Aug) AS Aug, SUM(Sep) AS Sep, SUM(Oct) AS Oct, SUM(Nov) AS Nov, SUM(Dec) AS Dec,
    CASE WHEN bla > 41 THEN 41 ELSE bla END AS bla
FROM cte
GROUP BY CASE WHEN bla > 41 THEN 41 ELSE bla END AS bla
ORDER BY CASE WHEN bla > 41 THEN 41 ELSE bla END AS bla
```